# Is it possible to create an account on Hedera that has both Ed25519 keys and ECDSA keys?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

When visiting the [Hedera portal](https://portal.hedera.com),
it generates 2 sets of keys for me:
an **ED25519** key and an **ECDSA** key.

However, these correspond to different accounts.

​
I would like to be able to operate a single account
which may be signed by either an ED25519 **or** an ECDSA key.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 7):

The same account **cannot** have 2 sets of keys,
that will not work for the underlying cryptography.
While both EdDSA and ECDSA both use elliptic curve cryptography,
they have different underlying algorithms,
and they use different configurations for their elliptic curves (Ed25519 and secp256k1),
and therefore it will not work at that level.

However, despite this, you **can** accomplish your objective,
of being able to "operate a single account which may be signed by either an ED25519 **or** an ECDSA key".
This is possible to do on Hedera, because the network supports
m-of-n multisig at a protocol level,
as an `Account` is separate from a `Key`.

Note that this is different from other EVM-compatible networks,
where an EOA (externally owned account) can have exactly one key only,
which means that multisig functionality needs to be
custom-programmed using smart contracts.

Here is how you can accomplish this using the Hedera JavaScript SDK:

(1) Create a 1-of-2 multisig `KeyList`,
comprised of one Ed25519 key and one ECDSA secp256k1 key.

```js
    const edKey = PrivateKey.generateED25519();
    const ecKey = PrivateKey.generateECDSA();
    const multisigPublicKeys = [edKey.publicKey, ecKey.publicKey];
    const multisigKeyList = new KeyList(multisigPublicKeys, 1);
```

(2) Next create `multisigAccountId` using
either `edKey` or `ecKey` from above,
and fund it with some HBAR.

(3) Update `multisigAccountId` using `AccountUpdateTransaction`
to change its key from the single key that was used during account creation,
to the 1-of-2 multisig `KeyList` instance created above.

```js
    const makeMultisigTx = new AccountUpdateTransaction()
        .setAccountId(multisigAccountId)
        .setKey(multisigKeyList)
        .freezeWith(client);
    const makeMultisigTxSignedByOneKey = await makeMultisigTx.sign(edKey);
    const makeMultisigTxSignedByAllKeys = await makeMultisigTxSignedByOneKey.sign(ecKey);
    const makeMultisigTxSubmitted = await makeMultisigTxSignedByAllKeys.execute(client);
```

Note that this `AccountUpdateTransaction` needs to be signed by both
of the keys in the `KeyList` (both `edKey` and `ecKey`).

(4) Now `multisigAccountId` can be signed using:

- **either**  `edKey` which is an Ed25519 key
- **or** `ecKey`, which is an ECDSA key

---

***Refs***

- [Hedera docs: Key](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/hedera-api/basic-types/key)
- [Hedera docs: Create a Key List](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/keys/create-a-key-list)
- [Hedera docs: Update an Account](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/cryptocurrency/update-an-account)